# Area 51: How should we deal with people commenting with answers to sample questions?

Tags: discussion, comments, area-51, flags

I'm starting to see more of this, and it fills up my Recent Activity list with useless comments.  It would be nice if there was a way to downvote them but that is not available for comments.  Would it be appropriate to flag them for moderator review?

Comment: I've tried educating people, and have gotten the response "I know, I'm just trying to be helpful."

Comment: Based on things like this, and the questions about "do they understand *off -topic*", I'm starting to understand why SE wanted the initial beta sites to be heavy on SO users - who understand the concept of a demo site...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Let them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56092/why-cant-committed-users-start-asking-answering-and-rating).

This will create more Google fodder which will increase the traffic, which increases the chance of the proposal succeeding.

So what happens if people answer off-topic questions? No big deal - they just won't be imported when the site goes Beta.

**Update:** see related feature request added by me: [Area51: allow answers much earlier](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70576/area51-allow-answers-much-earlier)

Comment: @BenV - thanks for accepting, appreciate it.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know what proposals you're referring to, but the people putting answers on my proposals are people who should know better, like [Adam Davis](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/5356/woodworking-and-carpentry/5385#5385) here (user Pollyanna on this site), so it seems like just typical meta.stackoverflow.com timewasting behaviour rather than a lack of user education.

Comment: Ha! I remember that one.  I know, I know, there's no room on Stack Exchange for levity, but it still makes me chuckle. [Here's the interaction](http://i.stack.imgur.com/qApgv.png) for those unable to see the now deleted question.