# Answering example questions on Area 51

Tags: discussion, area-51, example-questions

Hello, all!

Is it recommended / allowed to answer example questions in Area 51?

Comment: Can you clarify a bit? You mention Meta - are you suggesting answering the example questions in the new Discussion section? Suggesting that they be addressed in the Meta of the beta site? Or something else?

Comment: For those confused by @Grace Note's comment, the original title (which I edited while Grace was typing) said "meta" instead of "Area 51."

Comment: Apparently I did a confusing mistake in the title of the questio. I am sorry. Thank you for clarifying it, Popular Demand, that is exactly what I was trying to say.

Comment: Related; and why we don't allow answering example questions: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70576/area51-allow-answers-much-earlier/70641#70641

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would not recommend it because there is no real purpose to this.  The example questions are used to help define the scope and feel of the site.  Answers aren't really useful in the define stage.

Comment: +1, answers just clutter up the pages and distract from the real purpose of A51

Comment: Well, in this case wouldn't be useful to have it stated at the Area 51 FAQ? Or isn't this question frequently asked?

Comment: @brandizzi, I haven't seen it asked before.  But that doesn't mean this is the first time, but I don't think it is a very common question.

Comment: Well, I missed some documentation about it, but maybe Meta questions can take this role...

Answer (score 1):

I do agree with [@jzd](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77256/answering-example-questions-on-area-51/77258#77258) mostly, but I think it is not so absolute as he states.

Giving this discussion a chance, and to balance a bit:

Allowing example responses could not be such a bad idea since I have seen question I though were bad or useless get excellent very helpful answers.

I think the quality of the answers is a good indicator of the quality of the answers (caveat: [exceptions do exist](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/95/reversal)).

Just wanted to add another point of view.

Comment: I see questions themselves as very critical to define a site's scope. I guess I assume that questions will get good answers and therefore draw the line at example answers being just noise.

Comment: @jzd ok that is an interesting perpective but letting people answered will also be a test to see if there is a critical mass of **qualified individuals** for the site